# there's an extra newline before text ofstream c++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to copy user input text into a file and its doing that its just also adding a newline before the text starts any ideas how to make it not do that?

```
    getline(cin, userInput);

    while (userInput != endWrite) {
        storyTime << userInput << endl;         
        getline(cin, userInput);
    }
    storyTime.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, so it's impossible to be absolutely certain what may be going on--at first glance, my immediate guess would be that what you're seeing may result from some code you didn't quote. For one obvious possibility you might be asking the user for the name of the file where you're going to write the output:

```
std::string outputName;

std::cout << "Enter output file name: ";
std::cin >> outputName;

std::ofstream storyTime(outputName);

//...
```

In this case, the `std::cin >> outputName;` reads the filename--but you had to press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to get it to read that, and that press of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key  will leave a new-line in the input, so when you start the loop afterwards, it'll be read as a newline preceding the text the user enters afterwards.

#### Aside

Other than that, I'd normally try to keep the code somewhat simpler:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, userInput)) {
    storytime << userInput << '\n';
}
```

As a really general rule of thumb, I'd advise that a formatted read from a text file (using either `std::getline` or some `operator>>`) be as the condition of an `if`, `while`, or whatever. Doing so habitually makes it much easier to write input loops that process files correctly.

#### Demo

Just for what it's worth, here's some working code that doesn't insert an extra new-line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string userInput;

    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Please enter file name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, filename);

    std::ofstream output{filename};

    while (std::getline(std::cin, userInput)) {
        output << userInput << '\n';
    }
}
```